# Arrangements of a standard deck of $52$ playing cards if the denominations of the cards are ignored, so that only the suits are distinguished?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, card-games

I am struggling to see why my solution is wrong for this question.

My solution:

Number of arrangements of length $k$ is $4^k$ and,

since the maximum length is $52$ we have that the total possible ways is $4^1 + \ldots + 4^{52}$.

Comment: There are $4^k$ possible arrangements of length $k$ if you have four choices in each position.  However, you do not since there are only $13$ cards of each suit.

Comment: Suppose you only had $4$ cards (one of each suit). Would you think that there were $4^4$ ways to arrange them?

Comment: What you've counted is the number of ways you can take an essentially *unlimited* supply of cards of each suit and form "decks" of *up to* $52$ cards. But the problem you're asked to solve involves taking just $13$ cards of each suit and forming decks of *exactly* $52$ cards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your answer.  The first is you ignore the fact that there are exactly $13$ of each suit.  The number of arrangements of $k$ cards is $4^k$ for $k \le 13$, but for $k=14$ it counts arrangements with $14$ of the same suit, so the correct answer is $4^k-4$.  The discrepancy grows as $k$ gets larger.  If you look for [permutations of a multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_of_multisets) you can find information.

The second is that the question requires you have all $52$ cards in the arrangement, so you should not sum over $k$.